# How to select cells with the same value in a column and change them to a different value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help with the Google Sheets Apps Script to do the following:

1. select column T
2. apply filter and select only values "In review" in that column
3. change all values "In review" to "Done"
4. select and copy rows with "Done" value from columns A-L and N-R (i.e. skip column M).

I have tried recording a macro (with relative and absolute values) but it only works for the specific rows that were selected for the macro. It does not apply to the entire sheet.

Comment: `select and copy rows with "Done" value from columns A-L and N-R (i.e. skip column M).` What do you need to do after copying?

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your help! I will need to paste them in a different excel document so I only need them copied. Many thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts for helful content from this site as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const lastRow = spreadSheet.getLastRow();

  var arrayDoneRowNumber = []
  for (let i = lastRow; i > 1 ; i--) {
    var value = spreadSheet.getRange('T'+i).getValue();
    if (value == 'InReview') {
      spreadSheet.getRange("T"+i).setValue("Done");
      arrayDoneRowNumber.push(i)
    } else if (value == 'Done') {
      arrayDoneRowNumber.push(i)
    }
  }
  console.log(arrayDoneRowNumber)
}
```

This code snippet is responsible for the 1st three tasks you have mentioned. I will update the code when you have responded to my question for the 4th task.

**Note :-** Anyhow the array `arrayDoneRowNumber` has the row numbers of all the rows which have `Done` in column T. You can simply process further using this information of row numbers itself.